# How to change pagesize for particular category with custom collection on magento

Tags: php, magento

I am used magento version 1.8.0.1

I have created sale category but not assign product from backend. I want to display custom collection on that category page with magento default pagination.

I want to display 24 products per page on that category page.actually I have set 16 product per page from admin panel but this setting is for other all categories.

Please help me.

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to set page size for a particular category. The Page Size is actually a property of a `toolbar` block that present in `prodouct list` block. So basically what you need to do is to set page size to 24 for `toolbar` block, when your category get loaded.

For this you can use an observer method. In order to implement it, you need to know the id of category. Here I am taking my reference id as 23. Also for this let us set up a custom module, `Programmerrkt_PageSizeSetter`.

So first let us activate our module

Location : `app/etc/modules/Programmerrkt_PageSizeSetter.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Programmerrkt_PageSizeSetter>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Programmerrkt_PageSizeSetter>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Next, Let us configure our module,

Location: `app/code/local/Programmerrkt/PageSizeSetter/etc/config.xml`

```
<config> 
    <modules>
        <Programmerrkt_PageSizeSetter>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Programmerrkt_PageSizeSetter>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
                <observers>
                    <set_page_size_category>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>programmerrkt_pagesizesetter/observer</class>
                        <method>setPageSizeForCategory</method>
                    </set_page_size_category>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <programmerrkt_pagesizesetter>
                <class>Programmerrkt_PageSizeSetter_Model</class>
            </programmerrkt_pagesizesetter>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

As you can see, through our module, we are planning to observe an event `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after`. If we need to change some block properties, then this event would be the perfect and coolest event to listen to. Also you can see  we are planning to define a custom method `setPageSizeForCategory` in our observer. At last, we defined model section for our module inside `global` node. This is because observer is going to define in our model.

So it is the time to define our observer. So let us do that

Location: `app/code/local/Programmerrkt/PageSizeSetter/Model/Observer.php`

```
<?php
class Programmerrkt_PageSizeSetter_Model_Observer {

    /**
      *
      * Holds special category Id
      *
      * @var int
      *
    */
    protected $_categoryId = 23 ;

    /**
      *
      * Holds page Size
      *
      * @var int
      *
    */
    protected $_pageSize = 24 ;

    /**
      *
      * Use to set Page Size
      *
      * @param Varint Object  | $observer
      * 
      * 
    */
    public function setPageSizeForCategory($observer){

        $controller = $observer->getAction();
        $fullActionName = $controller->getFullActionName();
        $id = (int)$controller->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        //check whether current page is correspond to our special category. If not, returns
        if($fullActionName == "catalog_category_view" && $id == $this->_categoryId)
        {
            //check whether toolbar block exist or not
            $toolbar =  $controller->getLayout()->getBlock('product_list_toolbar');
            if($toolbar)
            {
                //sets page size to corresponding list mode
                $listMode = $toolbar->getCurrentMode();
                $toolbar = $toolbar->addPagerLimit($listMode , $this->_pageSize);
            }

        }

        return;
    }
}
```

So here in `setPageSizeForCategory` method, we ensures that we are standing in particular category page. If it is not, the control returns. If the page is the category that we are talking about, we will set page size to the toolbar block of that category.

The method that we use here to set page size is `addPagerLimit`. It has 3 parameters to pass. First one is list mode. It will be either grid/list. We are passing the current mode of toolbar block to this method, so that we dont need to really worry on list mode confusion. Next parameter is the size of page. Last one is label. Here we dont want to pass any labels. Hence not using it.

You can also see that our observer class has two properties `$_categoryId` and `$_pageSize`. First one holds the id of our special category and second one holds page size values. So you need to set these two properties according to your need. This will allow us `setPageSizeForCategory` untouched.

**Drawback** :- There is a small drawback for this approach. The event we are observing here will trigger in every page load. Since the scope our module is limitted to a particular category, most of the time our module will return without doing anything. I feel it as awkward and that's why I mentioned it here. But... common ! this is also a solution. Isn't it?

If anyone solve this issue in better way, let  me know and please share it. :)

Hope it helps

Comment: hi programmer_rkt thanks for custom module. when i saw your custom code in observer file and think on it. if we can set pagerlimit for particular category using custom layout update field of category backend. and I have added below code there and its working fine. here is my code.I think your code and my code meaning is same. 
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">     
     <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>24</limit></action>
     <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>24</limit></action>
</reference>

Comment: @SanjayPatel: You are absolutely right. I know the code described by you will work. Because that is what I am doing through the observer. But in your case, you need to apply it for a particular category. For that you can probably use the handler `CATEGORY_23`(if 23 is your category id). For every category there will be a unique handler like this. If you use this handler in your xml, you will get a better solution. I didn't try that code. I leave it for you :-).Please inform me if you can solve this through layout xml code

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML like this:

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
  <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>24</limit></action>
</reference>
```

In either a `local.xml` file or in the Category `Custom Design field`.

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: Hello liyakat, thanks for quick reply. I have added above code in custom design field but its not working. I want to change page limit for only one category.